# How to modify session controller to use lockable strategy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created the session controller and I'm following [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Find-a-user-when-you-have-their-credentials) .

I've already added lockable strategy in the model and run `rails db:migrate`

I want to update the failed attempts without using `warden.authenticate`
I read the devise docs, the lockable strategy and find the method valid_for_authentication.

How do I have to use valid_for_authentication?
I'm just skipping the sign_in if it's nil but I want to update the failed attempts. What method am I missing?

```
 def create
   @user = User.authenticate(params[:user][:email], params[:user][:password])
   sign_in(:user, @user) if @user&.valid_for_authentication?
   redirect_to root_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just sifted through the relevant source [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb#L92). As far as I can tell, using `@user&.valid_for_authentication?` will increase the `failed_attempts` counter and lock the account if the number of login attempts is exceeded. So this should work out of the box. If you want to test it I suggest using the `rails console` for that.

Comment: Yes, It has to do that but nothing happens because the user is nil when passing wrong pwd or email